# Documentation topic too short?

Tags: support, documentation

I created [this topic on loading files in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/drafts/9378). I added five examples and clicked submit for review. Now on my dashboard I see this:

```
Loading source files
- too short
Classes
- submitted for review, awaiting approval
```

"Classes" is an existing topic to which I proposed a change. Now I wonder: Is my topic also waiting for approval or has it fallen down some interplanetary vortex because it's 'too short'? Is it visible to other users at all?

**Edit** - something seems to have changed. Apparently I was stuck in edit mode, so it wasn't in review, even though I had clicked submit for review before...

Comment: I tried to start a `Code Contracts` section under `.Net Framework` and ran into a similar issue.

Comment: Is there any resolution of the `too short` issue?